# multiple complete types in GDBus introspection xml

Tags: c++, xml, introspection, dbus, gdbus

How can I  pass give multiple complete types in gdbus introspection xml. Example,

```
<method name="Frobate">
          <arg name="foo" type="ii" direction="in"/> 
          <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Deprecated" value="true"/>
</method>
```

When I tried this format, I am getting the error as

> Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Type of message, '(ii)',
>   does not match expected type '(null)'

when I am using

```
<method name="Frobate">
          <arg name="foo" type="(ii)" direction="in"/> 
          <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Deprecated" value="true"/>
</method>
```

the error becomes,

> Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Type of message, '(ii)',
>   does not match expected type '((ii))'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this way you can give multiple complete types,

```
 <method name='YourMethod'>"
  <arg type='i' name='name1' direction='in'/>"
  <arg type='i' name='name2' direction='in'/>"
 </method>
```